# python urllib2 check for both Http error AND urlerror

Tags: python, urllib

here's my problem:

i have 8 links in my script that changes based on other parts of the script. Of this link, only 1 will actually open the file i need, the other 7 could raise a 404 error (http) OR a 10061 error (connection refused, so URLerror).

i want my code to do this:

if error is 404, do nothing

if error is 10061, do nothing

if http.headers have content.type 'pdf', proceed to download.

code i wrote so far:

```
    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(link) 
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        if e.code == 404:
            print '404'
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
            if '10061' not in e.args 
                #Download code here
```

Comment: What question/problem do you have regarding this code?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm looking at your code and these 3 lines what you want to achieve it should most likely look like this: (not checked)

```
try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(link) 
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    if e.code == 404:
        print '404'
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    if e.code == 10061:
        print '10061'
content_type = response.get_header('content.type', default=None)
if content_type == 'pdf':
     #Download code here
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but i'm getting invalid syntax regarding "if e.code == 10061"